# Spring boot LDAP auto configuration - anonymous access

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

If the ldap server allows anonymous access, how do I configure the following properties.

spring.ldap.username
spring.ldap.password

If I leave out these properties, I am getting null pointer exception as internally hashtable is used.

Comment: I think `spring.ldap.anonymous-read-only = true` could work

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: and what if you provide a fake user/passw in combination with anonymous-read-only ?

Comment: It's trying to bind that user and fails

Comment: `spring.ldap.anonymous-read-only: true` in my `application.yml` totally worked for me with Spring Boot 2 & `spring-ldap 2.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

I run in the same problem with a transient dependency of Spring ldap security from another project and Spring boot 2.1 and Spring boot admin. My LDAP is not configured (with Spring boot) and a Spring boot admin console initiates a health check. Because of Spring boot auto-configuration a LDAP health check bean is enabled and then the check runs into a NullPointerException.

For this case I excluded the LdapHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class via @SpringBootApplication.

For your problem your maybe need more excludes. Please refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/auto-configuration-classes.html for existing auto configuration classes. Search for LDAP and try to exclude the found classes in your application.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Spring LDAP security, because an anonymous LDAP configuration (no user and password) was intended to work.

Answer (score -1):

I think, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952005/spring-security-using-ldap-and-group-membership/50952469#50952469) should able to use. Just don't provider membership detail.

Comment: Please don't just post a link as answer, include the core details in your answer.